# Is it possible to capture checkbox selection(crossmark like X) on flatten pdf

Tags: itext

I had an editable pdf with checkbox, after selection i flatten that pdf. from that flatten pdf i need to read the checkbox selection which is looks like crossmark(X), is there any possibility to read that checkbox selection.

Answer (score 0):

When you flatten a PDF, you take away all interactivity. If you have a check box field in an interactive form, and you flatten that form, the check box field is gone. That is the concept of flattening.

What happens in practice?

A check box field has two appearances. One appearance is `Off`. This appearance can be a path such as a simple square defined as a rectangle. Another appearance can have any name `On`, `Yes`, `1` or whatever is defined in the original form. The corresponding appearance can be the same square as the `Off` appearance with two extra lines that look like a cross, or the square with a character that looks like a check mark, or whatever was defined in the original form.

When you flatten the form, you throw away the name of the check box field, you throw away the widget annotation that corresponds with the field, and you throw away one appearance state (depending on the value of the check box field). The only thing that is left, is one of the two appearances.

If you no longer have the original form, you have no clue as to what this appearance could look like, hence you have no idea what to look for, nor where to look for a specific appearance.

You say that the appearance looks like a cross mark in your case, but whoever reads this question has no idea if this cross mark is a path that was constructed in graphics state, or a glyph that was added in text state.

Long story short: if you flatten first and then expect to be able to read a field value, your design is seriously flawed.

You have to ask yourself: why do I need to flatten the form? Maybe it's sufficient to make the fields read-only. If that's not sufficient, why don't you add an attachment to the PDF that contains the original field values? There are many different ways to work around your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

My requirement is to read the pdf, i don't know how they are creating the pdf whether it contains the acroforms or not. so far i'm reading the text based on the coordinates, similarly is there any way to read(like image/glyph/binary data) the cross mark.

Comment: Is there any way to read the cross mark as image or glyph or binary data.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. It all depends on how the check box is created. It could be a glyph; it could be just a bunch of lines (which makes it very difficult for a machine to interpret its meaning). In your comment, you say that you don't know whether it contains acroforms or not, but that is in contradiction with what you say in your question *"I had an editable pdf with checkbox, after selection i flatten that pdf."* The fact that you contradict yourself makes it impossible for any one to give you a useful answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 
Just for internal testing i created one editable pdf and flatten that pdf and trying to read from that.
This is the actual scenario
1.Agent has editable pdf with forms.
2.After filling the data they convert into non-editable.
  we dont know how they are generating non-editable pdf(may use some tools).
3.They will pass that non-editable pdf to my application
4.I need to extract text from that pdf. I'm extracting text based on coordinates.
5.Just like text extraction is there any way to extract that crossmark as image/glyph/binarydata ?

Comment: @krishna No and there probably never will. Your question sounds like: I have carrots and onions. I blend them together to make soup. Now please tell me how I can get the original carrots and onions back. It would take magic to do that, wouldn't it? Redesign your application so that you get the filled out forms *before* they are flattened. Fire the architect who made the original design.