# Reading CheckBox Cross (X) symbol from flattened PDF using itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

My question is based on below Stack Overflow question:

[Is it possible to capture checkbox selection(crossmark like X) on flatten pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29033995/is-it-possible-to-capture-checkbox-selectioncrossmark-like-x-on-flatten-pdf/30869032?noredirect=1#comment49799688_30869032)

Taken from above comment

**the appearance looks like a cross mark in your case, but whoever reads this question has no idea if this cross mark is a path that was constructed in graphics state, or a glyph that was added in text state.**

As per the statement, let us take first assumption as X mark was constructed with graphics state. Then do we have solution to read the data using C# and Itextsharp.

similarly let us take second assumption as X mark was constructed with a glyph, for this we have solution to read.

why I am asking is, i want to try with both the options to get the data. That flexibility i have.

Comment: In recent iText versions, we have introduced a `PathConstructionRenderInfo` object, that allows you to capture operations (such as lineTo, moveTo) and segments. For the moment, this functionality is used internally only, but that's what you'd need to explore if you'd want to find an X mark that is not a glyph, but a series of paths that are stroked. It's not impossible, but it's not trivial, though. I'd love to see an example of how you'd implement an *X detector*.

Comment: *no idea if this cross mark is a path that was constructed in graphics state, or a glyph that was added in text state.* - as a side remark, that is not a complete list of options, the cross mark can also be a bitmap image. Furthermore any of the options mentioned yet can also be wrapped in a pattern filling the original appearance stream, and patterns usually are not visited by text or graphics extractors.